# How to deserialize this JSON in c#?

Tags: java, c#, json

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name(1)",
    "var": 24,
    "type": "TEST"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Name(2)",
    "var": 24,
    "type": "TEST"
  },
...
```

Using TIntObjectMap in java and loading them like this works fine.
Couldn't find a way to do this in c#.

```
GSON.fromJson(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("file.json")),new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Definition>>() { }.getType()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
var myobjs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, MyObject>>(json);

public class MyObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int var { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

You can even make use of `dynamic` without using a class like `MyObject`

```
 dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
 Console.WriteLine(dynObj["1"].name);
```

This is the json I used (as you posted)

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Name(1)",
    "var": 24,
    "type": "TEST"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Name(2)",
    "var": 24,
    "type": "TEST"
  }
}
```

Comment: Error converting value 1 to type

Comment: @Indrz Given your json in question, I tested my code before posting and it works... So please post something better than `Error converting value 1 to type`

Comment: @Jim Why don't you simply copy&paste above codes. Don't type it.. **It works....**. Maybe my PC does something magic yours can't do :)

Comment: whats wrong with the my approach. if not useful i will delete it.

Comment: @PavanChandaka I didn't downvote it, but it is not correct... *type* to deseriaize should be `Dictionary<string, PersonDetails>` as in my answer. This is what the json in the question corresponds to..

Comment: @Jim ? Why did you remove your comments?

Comment: @Jim And you repeated it `n>=3` times, without reading the question and the answer carefully.